# How to increase Performance issue with ActiveRecord and database

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Rails 3.2.13, Mysql, Sql to filter records. Search is working perfect. But it is taking more time (more than a minute) to return result.

I cannot use eager loading here because raw sql query with join is used and i cannot use cache because our records will change frequently as per filters. FYI i have already used indexes in tables.

Any solution would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My Controller:

```
class ProjectReportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @results = ProjectCustomValueSearch.new(params[:teams], params[:contract_types], params[:retainer_ends], params[:retainer_ends_date], params[:status]).search
  end
end
```

My Model:

```
class ProjectCustomValueSearch
  attr_reader :teams, :contract_types, :retainer_ends, :retainer_ends_date, :status

  def initialize(teams, contract_types, retainer_ends, retainer_ends_date, status)
    @teams  = teams
    @contract_types = contract_types
    @retainer_ends = retainer_ends
    @retainer_ends_date = retainer_ends_date
    @status = status
  end

  def search
    #add status filter condition
    status_query = (@status=='Both' || @status.blank?) ? " p.status = 1 OR p.status = 5" : " p.status = #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(@status)}"

    other_conditions = ''

    #add team filter condition
    if (@teams!='DM' && @teams!='Web')
     other_conditions += " AND cv_team.value #{all_none_condition(@teams, 'cv_team.value')}"
    elsif (@teams=="DM" || @teams=="Web")
      other_conditions += " AND #{dm_or_web_condition(@teams)}"
    end

    #add cv_contract_type filter condition
    other_conditions += " AND cv_contract_type.value #{all_none_condition(@contract_types, 'cv_contract_type.value')}"

    #add cv_retainer_end value and cv_retainer_end date filter conditions
    other_conditions += " AND cv_retainer_end.value #{before_after_condition(@retainer_ends_date, @retainer_ends)}" if @retainer_ends_date.present?

    #Sql query is something like this:
    sql =  <<-sql
      select p.id, p.name as project_name,
       u_web_pm.firstname as web_pm_firstname,
       u_web_pm.lastname as web_pm_lastname,
       concat(u_marketing_pm.firstname, ' ', u_marketing_pm.lastname)  as marketing_pm_value, 
       u_client_contact.firstname as client_contact_firstname,
       u_client_contact.lastname as client_contact_lastname, 
       FORMAT(Round(cv_monthly_retainer.value, 0), 0) as monthly_retainer_value, 
       FORMAT(Round(cv_project_budget.value, 0), 0) as project_budget_value,
       cv_rates.value as rates_value, 
       cv_retainer_start.value as retainer_start_value,
       cv_retainer_end.value as retainer_end_value,
       cv_contract_type.value as contract_type_value, 
       cv_team.value as team_value,
       cv_discount.value as discount_value, 
       cv_account_rep.value as account_rep_value,
       FORMAT(Round(cv_project_budget.value / 150, 0), 0) as budget_project,
       FORMAT(Round(cv_monthly_retainer.value / 150, 0), 0) as budget_retainer,
       FORMAT(Round(sum(time_entry.hours), 0), 0) as total_hours
       from projects p

       #Web PM
       left join custom_values as cv_web_pm on p.id = cv_web_pm.customized_id and cv_web_pm.custom_field_id=4
       left join users as u_web_pm on cv_web_pm.value = u_web_pm.id

       #Marketing PM
       left join custom_values as cv_marketing_pm on p.id = cv_marketing_pm.customized_id and cv_marketing_pm.custom_field_id=5
       left join users as u_marketing_pm on cv_marketing_pm.value = u_marketing_pm.id

       #Client Contact
       left join custom_values as cv_client_contact on p.id = cv_client_contact.customized_id and cv_client_contact.custom_field_id=6
       left join users as u_client_contact on cv_client_contact.value = u_client_contact.id

       #Monthly Retainer
       left join custom_values as cv_monthly_retainer on p.id = cv_monthly_retainer.customized_id and cv_monthly_retainer.custom_field_id=7

       #Project Budget
       left join custom_values as cv_project_budget on p.id = cv_project_budget.customized_id and cv_project_budget.custom_field_id=8

       #Rates
       left join custom_values as cv_rates on p.id = cv_rates.customized_id and cv_rates.custom_field_id=9

       #Retainer Start
       left join custom_values as cv_retainer_start on p.id = cv_retainer_start.customized_id and cv_retainer_start.custom_field_id=10

       #Retainer End
       left join custom_values as cv_retainer_end on p.id = cv_retainer_end.customized_id and cv_retainer_end.custom_field_id=11

       #Contract Type
       left join custom_values as cv_contract_type on p.id = cv_contract_type.customized_id and cv_contract_type.custom_field_id=12

       #Team
       left join custom_values as cv_team on p.id = cv_team.customized_id and cv_team.custom_field_id=13

      #additional filters
      where #{status_query}
      #{other_conditions} 

      Group BY p.id
      order by p.name ASC

      sql

      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end

private

 def all_none_condition(str, field='')
  case str
  when 'All'
   return " = '' or #{field} <> '' "
  when 'Any'
   return " <> '' "
  when 'None'
   return " = '' "
  else
   return " = #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(str)}"
  end
 end

 def dm_or_web_condition(str)
   case str
   when 'DM'
     return " (cv_team.value='DM 1' OR cv_team.value='DM 2') "  
   when 'Web'
     return " (cv_team.value='Web 1' OR cv_team.value='Web 2') " 
   end
 end

 def before_after_condition(date, condition)
  case condition
   when 'Before'
    return " < #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(date)} and cv_retainer_end.value <> ''"
   when 'After'
    return " > #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(date)} and cv_retainer_end.value <> ''"
   end
  end
end
```